# AngularJS / Typeahead - Delay call to $scope method

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I have following input field code snippet from here I am calling AngularJS `$scope` method in the following way

```
<input class="search-txt-input"
       id="partner_name"
       name="partner_name"
       title="Partner Name"
       type="text"
       autocomplete="off"
       ng-model="selectedPartner"
       typeahead="partner as partner.name for partner in retrievePartnerList($viewValue)"
       typeahead-items="2"
       typeahead-min-length="3">
```

So when I type a minimum of 3 characters in the text field, it will fire an AJAX call to to `retrievePartnerList` function.

Also my server response is very slow, so for 10 characters 7 Ajax calls comes in queue and after some time I am getting a TimeOutError.

So to solve this I am trying to find a way using which I can delay the call to `retrievePartnerList()` method, so that less AJAX calls will be sent and it probably reduce the burden to my server.

So I am not sure how I can use `setTimeout()` function here.

Let me know if any one of you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can easily delay firing off matching by specifing the `typeahead-wait-ms` attribute. As the name of the attribute implies, it takes a value in milliseconds and will delay matching , waiting specified number of milliseconds after user stopped typing before firing requests to the server.

Here is a demo showing this in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/fHLqDx?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its working in the above js fiddle, but not working in my code not sure what could be the reason, I have just added typeahead-wait-ms="10000". But still it is triggering after every key types

Comment: I am using 0.3.0 version of the API may be typeahead-wait-ms is not added in this version..Will have to check

Comment: @DeanM support for the `typeahead-wait-ms` was only added in the 0.5.0 version (there were some tentative in 0.4.0 but 0.4.0 wasn't working quite right). You would have to upgrade to 0.5.0 to have it working as in my plunker.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but now I am using "ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.min.js" but still typeahead-wait-ms attribute is not working for me, here is my input element after adding it

Comment: <input class="search-txt-input"
                       id="partner_name"
                       name="partner_name"
                       title="Partner Name"
                       type="text"
                       autocomplete="off"
                       ng-model="selectedPartner"
                       typeahead="partner as partner.name for partner in retrievePartnerList($viewValue)"
                       typeahead-wait-ms="10000"
                       typeahead-items="2"
                       typeahead-min-length="3"
                >

Comment: Ok, now its working for the change I did is , I just added typeahead-wait-ms element above typeahead and it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Check `AngularStrap` solution: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/directives/typeahead.js

OR

It can be easily done like this in javascript:

```
var autocomplete = $('#searchinput').typeahead().on('keyup', delayRequest);

function dataRequest() {
    // api request here
}

function delayRequest(event) {
    if(delayRequest.timeout) {
        clearTimeout(delayRequest.timeout);
    }

    var target = this;

    delayRequest.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        dataRequest.call(target, event);
    }, 200); // 200ms delay
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already seen this approach, but in my case I am not calling typeahead function from js file but triggering it from view automatically..

Comment: Have you check `AngularStrap`: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/directives/typeahead.js

Comment: I checked this, but I am not understanding this as I am new to Angular js framework and have a basic IDea of its working. For my project I have used http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and I am using Typeahead module(example given at the end of this link)